# CakePHP find in another datasource

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hie 
I have configured my application to use two different datasources and i can interchange with the following code
    $this->ModelA->setDataSource('dbConf');
to use dbConf datasource.
 dataSource dbConf has tables tableA, tableB. 
 dataSource default has tables tableX, tableZ.

I am writing my code in tableX controller and i want to do a query that will retrieve data from tableA in the dbConf datasource. I can change to the dbConf datasource but the challenge i am having is on writing the find query to the tableA data source just because in the dbConf dataSource i do not have tableX which can allow me to write
    $this->tableX->tableA->find('all');
How can i do the find in tableA when the two databases do not have similar tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use ClassRegistry:

```
$tableA = ClassRegistry::init('tableA');
$tableA->find(etc);
```